# Python - How to sort date string in a Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, string, sorting

I have a df pandas.core.series.Series such that:

```
0        11/8/16
1        11/8/16
2        6/12/16
3       10/11/15
4       10/11/15
          ...   
9989     1/21/14
9990     2/26/17
9991     2/26/17
9992     2/26/17
9993     12/30/17
```

If I use `max()` on it, it shows the latest date as '9/9/17', instead of the actual maximum which is, in this case '12/30/17'.

I understand why it is happens - because 9 > 1.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'd suggest using [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert those to date objects for comparison.

Comment: This doesn't look like a numpy array. What exactly is the object? Can you provide the code to construct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the dates to timestamps first:

```
import pandas as pd
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m/%d/%y")
>>> df["date"].max()
```

Comment: This would work, but it would be good to indicate when using 3rd party libraries that require installation, like pandas.

Comment: What OP provided looks like a `pandas.Series` and not an "array" as they claim.